# Runtime Error from addcomment in if statement in nested loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code that can loop range across selected sheets to times the value for each cell in selected ranges and add comment on each cell, but it failed when it comes to add comment to each cell in ranges that across selected sheets. The error is 1004 runtime error. Does anyone know what is happening here? I have done the research on Internet and forum but can't find any answer.

```
Sub X2()

Dim MySheet As Worksheet 'For sheet in selected sheets
Dim MyCell As Range 'For cell in selected Ranges

If Selection.CountLarge > 1000 Then Exit Sub 'Avoid loop over 1000

If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then 'Range that across sheets

    For Each MySheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        For Each MyCell In Range(Selection.Address)

            If Not MySheet.Range(MyCell.Address).Comment Is Nothing Then
                MySheet.Range(MyCell.Address).Comment.Text vbNewLine & Now & "_" & MySheet.Range(MyCell.Address).Value & "_" & Environ("Username") _
                , Len(MySheet.Range(MyCell.Address).Comment.Text) + 1 _
                , False
                'this program works fine
            Else

                MySheet.Range(MyCell.Address).AddComment Now & "_" & MySheet.Range(MyCell.Address).Value & "_" & Environ("Username")
                'Runtime Error 1004 for this code _
                i want to addcommet for each cell that _
                acoss sheets
            End If

            MySheet.Range(MyCell.Address).Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = False

            MySheet.Range(MyCell.Address).Value = MySheet.Range(MyCell.Address).Value * 2

        Next MyCell
    Next MySheet

Else

    For Each MyCell In Selection
        If Not MyCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
            MyCell.Comment.Text vbNewLine & Now & "_" & MyCell.Value & "_" & Environ("Username") _
            , Len(MyCell.Comment.Text) + 1 _
            , False
        Else
            MyCell.AddComment Now & "_" & MyCell.Value & "_" & Environ("Username")
        End If

        MyCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

        MyCell.Value = MyCell.Value * 2
    Next MyCell

End If
```

Comment: Break down the line of the error (the one after the `else` statement) into single logical steps. Go through each logical step one by one and check all the values you are working with. Find the exact step that throws the error. Update your question with your findings.

Comment: Hi David, it happened even when i use the simple code:
MyCell.AddComment "A", i think problem happen when i try to use addcomment method through range that across sheets.

Comment: I see. Take a loot at the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-addcomment-method-excel) and try the example. Make an update if you can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
    MyCell.AddComment
    MyCell.Comment.Text Now & "_" & MyCell.value & "_" &  Environ("Username")
```

Comment: Hi Maddy Nikam, it stop and pop error 1004 at the line MyCell.Addcomment, which is same stuff from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code from the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-addcomment-method-excel):

```
Worksheets(1).Range("E5").AddComment "Current Sales"
```

If it works, you can work your way up from there.

Comment: Just found that you can not use addcomment method inside nested for each loop but you can use one for each loop. I think it might be a bug for Mircrosoft VBA